# Momentum average on phase space for free particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I'm studying from Greiner statistical mechanics, and he uses an approximation which I don't really understand.

On averaging over many phase-space points we have

> $$\langle\vec{p}^2\rangle=3\langle p_x^2\rangle=3\langle p_y^2\rangle=3\langle p_z^2\rangle$$
>   since no direction in space is preferred, i.e.,
>   $$\sqrt{\langle\vec{p}^2\rangle}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\left(\sqrt{\langle p_x^2\rangle}+\sqrt{\langle p_y^2\rangle}+\sqrt{\langle p_z^2\rangle}\right).$$
>   Therefore, we make the approximation
>   $$\epsilon=c\left(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2\right)^{1/2}\approx\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\vert p_x\vert+\vert p_y\vert+\vert p_z\vert\right)$$

Can someone please explain this approximation?

Comment: Hi Juan Pablo Arcila: Which page in [Greiner](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=greiner+statistical+mechanics)? Ah found it: Example 6.2 p. 153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim on Greiner is

$$ \langle\vec{p}^2\rangle = 3\langle p_x^2\rangle = 3\langle p_y^2\rangle = 3\langle p_z^2\rangle $$

This claim follows from the fact that

$$ \text{E}[p^2] = \text{E}[p_x^2] + \text{E}[p_y^2] + \text{E}[p_z^2] $$

and that $(x,y,z)$ are indistinguishable:

$$ \text{E}[p^2] = 3 \text{E}[p_x^2] = 3 \text{E}[p_y^2] = 3 \text{E}[p_z^2] $$

The rest follows if you substitute all of $(x,y,z)$ with either one.

Comment: But how do you know the first claim?

Comment: I am not sure, looking into it right not

Comment: @JuanPabloArcila I redid the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now :D